# How to find the table or dataset which is responsible for standard or detailed billing export using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Is there any way to find the table or dataset which is responsible for standard or detailed billing export using python.

Comment: Billing data tables are automatically created in the BigQuery dataset.This [doc](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/bq-examples#table-name) provides some examples of how to query the Cloud Billing data exported to and stored in BigQuery. If you want the queries in python, integrate the queries with python using this [link.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-using-python/)

Comment: Im asking how to find the table name so that i can query against it

Comment: yeah but how to get the dataset name which contains the the billing export table programatically without checking the console.

Edit: Im trying to monitor organization wise, not project wise so I cant place the table name as an environment variable

Answer (score 0):

To query the Cloud Billing data in BigQuery, you need to specify the table name in the **FROM** clause. The table name is determined using three values:

```
project.dataset.BQ_table_name.
```

- ***Project*** is the ID of the Google Cloud project you set up that contains your BigQuery dataset.
- ***dataset*** is the name of the BigQuery dataset you set up to contain the [BigQuery tables](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery-setup#create-bq-dataset) with your exported Cloud Billing data.
- ***BQ_table_name*** is the name of the BigQuery table that contains the exported Cloud Billing data that you want to query. There are three BigQuery tables that contain Cloud Billing data:

1. [Standard usage cost table](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery-tables/standard-usage): In your BigQuery dataset, this table is named `gcp_billing_export_v1_<BILLING_ACCOUNT_ID>.`
2. [Detailed usage cost table](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery-tables/detailed-usage): In your BigQuery dataset, this table is named `gcp_billing_export_resource_v1_<BILLING_ACCOUNT_ID>.`
3. [Pricing table](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery-tables/pricing-data): In your BigQuery dataset, this table is named cloud_pricing_export.

Refer to the [cloud document](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery-tables#billing_data_tables) for Understanding the Cloud Billing data tables in BigQuery.